# How does one "nice" a PID via htop after the process has begun?

Tags: nice, htop

Let's say I'm running a multicore process. How do I "nice" this via htop after submission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My version of htop displays this as the help line:

`F1Help  F2Setup F3Search F4Invert F5Tree  F6SortBy F7Nice - F8Nice + F9Kill  F10Quit`

So you would hit <kbd>F7</kbd> to decrease the "nice value", and <kbd>F8</kbd> to increase it
(the former may require special privileges).

Comment: It looks like this is correct. What determines the "level" of niceness?

Comment: On my system, `NI` goes from 0 to 19.

Comment: Hi! At least on Linux, nice values go from -20 (highest priority) to 19 (lowest); but one has to be root or otherwise have adequate powers to lower a process' nice value. I don't know if this is standard: see your system's man pages for commands `nice` and `renice` to know more.